# Secrets Gradle plugin - access key programmatically?

Tags: android

So the docs show how to use the key for Google Maps in the manifest (the key itself is defined in `local.properties`):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin

But for Places API I need to access it programmatically:

```
Places.initialize(applicationContext, "API_KEY")
```

How can I do it with the secrets plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be available with `BuildConfig.MAPS_API_KEY`

Comment: Thanks, can you include the import for BuildConfig?